# Is there an algorithm to explore all cells in a grid, excluding redundant cells?

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm which can explore a whole grid, excluding adjacent cells.

[image]

The picture is showing green blob where I am, and blue blobs what I can see. Now I want to visit every cell on the grid ("see" every cell). Which means I want to move in such a way that I don't have to move to every cell, skipping adjacent cells.

Is there a name for an algorithm like that or what can be recommended here? Please note, the grid can be any size any number of cells, the constraints remain the same: I can always "see" adjacent cells.

Comment: Are there any obstacles in the grid?

Comment: Is the starting position always such that you see a corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the closest term is padding/stride?
In your case you pad 1, and stride 3.

```
for(var i  = 1; i<n; i+=3){
    for(var j = 1; j<m; j+=3){
        //visit your cell
    }
}
```

There may arise a problem if you don't have a multiple of 3 rows/columns.

Consider the cases (grid width is not the same) when you iterate to the right. x is a cell. O is a cell you will visit with above for loop

```
...xxxxxx
...xOxxOx <-- ok you can see everything
...xxxxxx

...xxxxx
...xOxxO  <-- ok you can see everything
...xxxxx

...xxxx 
...xOxxF   <-- ko you are out of bounds and should have taken the "first" column
...xxxx
```

The ko case appear when grid.width%3 = 1

so you may handle it separately

```
for(var i  = 1; i<n; i+=3){
    for(var j = 1; j<m; j+=3){
        //visitCell(i,j)
    }
}
if(n%3 == 1){
    for(var j = 1; j<m; j+=3){
        visitCell(n-1,j);
    }
}

if(m%3 == 1){
    for(var i = 1; i<n; i+=3){
        visitCell(i,m-1);
    }
}

if(m%3 == 1 && n%3 == 1){
    visitCell(n-1,m-1);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khvsz4fx/

Comment: Wow that helped me understand it a lot more. Now for the advanced scenario, what if a cell is blocked and cannot be visited? How can we approach that?

Comment: probably check it for everyCell, something like visitIfCell(i,j) which will call visitCell if and only if cell(i,j) is not blocked. Alternative could be to build your cells to visit as a list, and remove the blocked cells from that list. I would use the former one because iterating and checking a blocked cell may not be the bottleneck